# Assertion Failed error when minimumPeriod is set to 0

Tags: polkadot-js, timestamp, async-backing

I'm currently working on upgrading a parachain to use Asynchronous Backing which requires a change in the pallet_timestamp making the MinimumPeriod = 0

```rust
impl pallet_timestamp::Config for Runtime {
    ....
    type MinimumPeriod = ConstU64<0>;
}
```

This is needed because multiple parachain  blocks can be built on the same relay chain block therefore they will have the same timestamp.

After applying this change every extrinsic starts failing with a message `Assertion Failed`. Here's an example trying to make a simple transfer
[image]
[image]

This also happens with every other extrinsic.

Changing `MinimumPeriod` to a value other than 0 fixes the problem but is not a solution since it must be set to that value for async-backing to work properly.

We also observed that this bug was also present when trying to submit an extrinsic using polkadotJs Api.

[Linked Github Issue](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/9970)